# Changing state based off result of helper function in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've imported a helper function into my App component that should fire after the submission of a text input form, and then immediately set the state based off the result of that function. However, the state is staying the same - even I return 'false' from the test function.

How do I change the state with this function? My App component:

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { test } from './testBalance'

import Nav from './Nav'

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      text: '',
      isTested: true
    }
  }

  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!test(this.state.text)){
      this.setState({
        isTested: false
      })
    }
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    })
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Nav/>
        <h1 className="black-text">Test balanced parenthesis in the box below..</h1>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

my test function:

```
export function test(text){
  return false
}
```

Comment: I think the test function belongs in the main component as a custom function. What are you trying to do, for abstraction purposes..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to bind your callback functions so that the `this` inside of `handleSubmit` and `handleChange` actually refers to the class.

```
constructor(){
    ...
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

I would also recommend changing `handleSubmit` like so:

```
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
        isTested: test(this.state.text),
    })
}
```

You can also just pass `this.handleSubmit` as the callback directly like so

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ... >
```